# phpinfo() is not working it shows blank page but other php working

Tags: php

I am completely lost as to why this is happening.
I am on a server x10hosting.
I have a PHP file named "phpinfo.php".
Inside this file it says

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

It doesn't say `<? phpinfo(); ?>`

For all I can tell it should be perfectly fine. If I try other PHP code they work.

For example

```
<?php
echo '<div>hello World</div'; 
?>
```

works perfectly. What could possibly be the problem?

Comment: check return value of phpinfo() function.

Comment: You may not be allowed to use that function. Have a look at [*disable\_function*](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions).

Comment: also, possible that fastcgi is not configured properly.plz refer https://www.itsupportwale.com/blog/fixed-nginx-showing-blank-php-pages-with-fastcgi-or-php-fpm/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`phpinfo()` is disabled for free accounts on that particular hosting provider. You have to upgrade if you want access to `phpinfo()`.

Comment: okay thanks i was so confused. i was thinking it can't get easier than that function if i can't figure out this one i stand no chance

Answer (score 10):

Use `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);` you might find an error saying that `phpinfo` is on the restricted functions list (x10hosting may not want anyone to find out their configurations/ weaknesses etc.).

Comment: Doing that got me a message "phpinfo() has been disabled for security reason" which explains everything !

Answer (score 5):

Check your `php.ini` file, and grep for `disable_function`:

```
cat php.ini | grep -in "disable_function"
```

If the output has `phpinfo` in this line as such:

> 386:disable_functions = show_source, system, shell_exec, passthru,
>   exec, phpinfo, popen, proc_open

edit the file and remove `phpinfo` from this line and save. You may need to restart httpd

```
service httpd restart
```

Comment: Actually this was my issue. Thanks